# how to automatically retrieve selected value

Tags: forms

is there a way to automatically retrieve selected value from dropdown or radio to form below? example in the image below, if i select radio button "randy", then the value "randy" automatically fill in the form Nama below

[image]

```
$header1 = array('Name'); // Prepare table header
$query = db_select("homo", "r"); // Select table  
$query->fields("r", array("nama")); // Select fields    
$result = $query->execute(); // Execute query 
$rows = array();
while($data = $result->fetchObject()){ // Looping for filling the table rows  
$rows[] = array( // Fill the table rows
  $data->nama,
  );
}
$form['table'] = array (
 '#type' => 'tableselect',
 '#header' => $header1,
 '#options' => $rows,
 '#multiple' => FALSE,  
);
$form['f1'] = array(
 '#title' => t('Detail Anggota'),
 '#type' => 'fieldset',    
);
$form['f1']['namaa'] = array(
 '#title' => t('Nama'),
 '#type' => 'textfield',    
 '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Form API Ajax](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax). There you can see how to use it, [Examples for developers](http://drupal.org/project/examples) include good ajax forms too.

Just remember, to set value to display, use `$form_state['input']`, not `$form_state['values']`.